# Why is SharpVectors not showing colored SVGs in WPF .Net Core but shows colored in WPF .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, .net-core, sharpvectors

[image: et]

The first Window is WPF Framework, while the Window in the background is of .Net Core. I use SharpVectors to load SVG files to images. 
I am having issue coz the .Net Core won't show coloured SVG files.

```
...
xmlns:svgc="http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/svgc/"
...
<Image Source="{svgc:SvgImage ../Resources/sample1.svg}" Stretch="Uniform" />
```

Comment: Strange! but can you post the URL or the image file for testing?

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jogwa-sports.appspot.com/o/wfh_1.svg?alt=media&token=f4dbb43c-4b2b-43a2-a43b-53924445c1c8

Comment: https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors/issues/136 you answered well. Thanks @Paulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using

```
<PackageReference Include="SharpVectors" Version="1.0.0" />
```

instead of

```
<PackageReference Include="SharpVectors.Reloaded" Version="1.6.0" />
```

When I upgraded and used the right library, it worked well. Colors.

https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors/issues/136